# Why do other Visual Studio devs need to Nuget dependencies I have already added?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, nuget

A bit of a noob question, but I'm wondering why, after I have checked in a project, other developers need to use Nuget to get all the packages I had included. Shouldn't those DLLs be in the references folder already?

Is there any strategy to make things a bit more painless? I have to go through the list of all the references and make suggestions to them about what they should attempt to pull down to make the project compile?

Regards,

Chris

Comment: Have you checked in these dependencies? And of course _should_ you? is the other question...

Comment: I have checked everything in, but when they do a Get Latest, they get build errors complaining they don't have ELMAH, System.Web.Optimizations, etc... Is there some way to mitigate this?

Comment: Ah, I see by default .dll's are excluded from the repo. So, if I want to use Nuget, but I need other developers to have access to the assemblies it brings in, what's the best practice here?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles over this, please have a look at Nuget Powertools. There is an option to restore Nuget packages that reconciles this issue across devs - very nice :)